# How to get bloom effect when there is a gradient background?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

So I want this kind of effect
[image]

trying to emulate the dark room effect but was thinking of adding some sort of gradient to the background to make it look interesting

but the moment i do that i get this
[image]

I lose the effect of the night time style was wondering if there is a good way to do this in in evee. My plan was to make something that emulates a lit screen in a dark room

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your images, but it looks like it's possible that the World Lighting from your scene is too bright for the bloom and kind of "overrides" it. If you want to keep the look of the background without having it influence the lighting in a scene, you can mix your (gradient) background with a plain (dark) background with a Mix Shader, using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* node as a mix factor. This will separate the environment "look" from it's lighting and reflections.

[image: Path]

Comment: hey so ya i have the is light ray on the shader https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGBd6bgEAxY used this guys tutorial to create the background, I can't seem to find the the world lighting thing u said about, i think the effect u have is exactly what im looking for, do u mean the strenght level in the background node form world? I'm still new to blender so am confused if u could post ur blend file that would be super helpfup!

Comment: just did the same procedure as urs from the pic and still am not getting the glowy effect that i have shown in my first pic

Comment: Not sure what's going on then. Maybe something to do with your bloom settings? It's hard to tell without knowing more about your file. Sorry I can't post my .blend file because I just made it as a quick mockup and never bothered saving it.

Comment: ah gotchu is there a way to chat on stack exchange i think there was a way but its been long time so i forgot i can share my setting or even the blend file

Comment: You can upload your file here - https://blend-exchange.com/ Just copy the link they give you, edit your own question (on this page), and paste in the link. Unfortunately I have to leave my computer right now, but I'll take a look later when I get back. Hopefully someone else will have a better answer for you in the meantime.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem here. This doesn't have to do with world lighting as much as it does with your objects materials. If you want something to "glow" (with a bloom), you need to use Emission textures. I'm not sure the effect you're going for on your screen, but only one of your screen "textures" has an emission, but it's mixed with Diffuse and it's kind of hard to tell what it does. The other texture has simply a purple Diffuse shader. If you switch that purple Diffuse Shader for a purple Emission Shader and turn up the strength to something like 10, you'll see it glow.

Comment: ohh ok thank you ill try that